# Konjunktiv II in negative contexts

Tags: subjunctive, subordinate-clause

I have recently read that when subordinate clauses have a 'negative element', the subjunctive can be used to represent this.
For example: 'es gibt nichts, was schwieriger wäre, als der Gebrauch des Konjunktivs'
This was one of those elements of grammar that took me aback a little. It seems unusual.
So, to put it in a very simple context, would I be understood I was to say "ich bin traurig, dass es klein wäre", meaning "I am sad because it is small"? 
And would it be possible to use the conditional with 'würden' (as I consider this another variant of Konjunktiv II) as an alternative to this type of sentence?

Answer (score 1):

> <s>Ich bin traurig, **dass** es klein wäre.</s>

This sentence makes no sense, because **dass** introduces a new fact here. Facts are contradicting *Konjunktiv II*.

> Ich bin (nicht) traurig, **wenn** es klein wäre.

**Wenn** in contrary introduces a condition. That's compatible with *Konjunktiv II*. English sees this completely the same:

*I won't be unhappy if it was small.*

> Es gibt nichts, **was/das** schwieriger ist.
>
> Es gibt nichts, **was/das** schwieriger wäre.

Don't confuse **was/das** with **dass**. They are relative pronouns so they don't introduce new facts but explain another thing – *nichts*. Again, English sees it absolutely the same:

*There's nothing that is more difficult.*

*There's nothing that was more difficult.*

Comment: Thank you for the response. Am I right in thinking, then, that the Konjunktiv II can be used to present a negative element mainly in relative clauses?

Comment: The *Konjunktiv II* isn't about negation but about irreal or contrafactual things: *Wir haben nicht verloren, was wir ohnehin nie hätten gewinnen können.* There's a negation *nie* in the relative clause, but the important thing is the action *gewinnen* is declared contrafactual by using the *Konjunktiv II* *hätten*. In English, this is just the same: *We did not lose what we **couldn't** win anyway.*

Comment: So presented with this sentence: 'es gibt nicht eine einzige Großstadt, die nicht ihr Gesicht in zwei Jahrzehnten gründlich gewandelt hätte' could you please explain why the Konjunktiv II is used here? I think that would address my question more closely.

Comment: That sentence is also fine with *Indikativ*. If you use *Indikativ*, all you tell is facts. If you use *Konjunktiv II* instead, you expect the reader to have knowledge you want to contradict. E.g.: *Ich mag Berlin. Hier ist alles anders als vor 20 Jahren. Ganz anders als in München.* – *Es gibt nicht eine einzige Großstadt, die nicht ihr Gesicht in zwei Jahrzehnten gründlich gewandelt hätte.* This *hätte* instead of *hat* means *Hey, your idea is wrong. Tell me what Munich looked like if it **hadn't** changed, too.*

Comment: I think all the confusion about *Konjunktiv* English speakers have comes from the fact the English subjunctive/irrealis forms are shared with other tenses so the subjunctive isn't easy to spot in English. But at its grammatical core, German and English are very similar when it comes to the subjunctive mood. It's only well hidden.

Comment: Yes you are right in saying that. I appreciate you taking the time to answer me. My confusion here stems from the fact that the grammar book I use states that using 'hat' rather than hätte' in the example that I gave above about the City would make the sentence I quote 'much more positive'.

Comment: Which grammar book?

Comment: Hammers German Grammar, which I have always considered the most reliable, but...

Comment: If you told me the section, I would read what they wrote myself. Maybe I get what they mean.

Comment: That would be great, thank you! It is section 14.5.5 or with an earlier version right at the back of the subjunctive and imperative section under 'other uses of the subjunctive'

Comment: Argh, they renumber it between revisions! I need the topic title.

Comment: Yes I've just noticed that. It is 'other uses of the subjunctive' at the back of the chapter on verb moods (imperative and subjunctive) hope this helps

Comment: They write: *The indicative is almost always a possible alternative but it can sound **less tentative**.* That's exactly what I wrote. The *Konjunktiv II* focuses on contradicting what others think. Forget that addition "much more positive" addition at that single sentence, it puts you on the wrong track.

Comment: It's amazing how much one sentence can mislay you. I think this section is very poorly explained compared to some other parts of the book that are in a large amount of detail. I will focus on the explanation you have given me. Thanks very much for your time

Comment: *Konjunktiv II* == *irreal, contrafactual, contradicting* That's the simple equation.